# EF Core 5, Order Entities by date in child collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, fluent

I have a simple relation like

```
public class Invoice{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  ICollection Product Products {get;set;}
}

public class Product {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public DateTime ReceptionDate {get;set;}
  public virtual Invoice Invoice{get;set;}
}
```

I want to present invoices ordered by Product ReceptionDate, so the invoice with the most recent Product goes first. I'm also paging the results.

I tried

```
invoices.OrderByDescending(x => x.Products.Select(y => y.ReceptionDate)).Skip(x).Take(y);
```

But it's not even a valid query.

Could not find a similar question by searching.

Thanks.

Edit:
Also tried Sergey solution but it's too slow, because it calls ToArray() fetching thousands of records from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
var query=Products
    .GroupBy(g => new { g.Invoice.Id, g.ReceptionDate})
    .Select(g => new 
        {
           Id=g.Key.Id
           ReceptionDate=g.Key.ReceptionDate
        })
    .OrderBy(x => x.ReceptionDate)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I can't use this query, I have thousands of invoices and products and the call to 'ToArray()' is too slow. Also i can't use Distinct() before the 'ToArray()' call in ef core 5 as it's not supported.

Comment: I didn' t now that you will have a network trafic problem. Try another query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this:

```
invoices.OrderByDescending(x => x.Products.Max(y => y.ReceptionDate));
```

Comment: It's a valid query but it's not ordering the invoices by product reception date.